# How format horizontal axis as a date on the Gant chart in the Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: charts, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, gantt

This is my [template](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MaBBymN3t3zG5_IkCz6jxehrqZGCJSuJgJzw4VfozW4/edit#gid=780546987) for the Gant chart that I modified from other  chart somewhere from the Internet.

How to format the horizontal axis as a date but not some number like it is now?

I want to see that on the vertical axis should be the name of the task and on the horizontal axis a date. And the chart should give me sense how many days some task will require and it should be noticed by boundary days below on the horizontal axis.

Comment: Don't tag with Excel if you don't use Excel. It's not the same as Google Sheets.

Comment: @teylen, thank you! Roger that